# Save values global in NodeRED

Tags: global-variables, node-red

We are working with MQTT messages, process these messages and call a REST service to send the information to another system.

Now we need to save some values from the MQTT message to compare these values with other messages. Is it possible to create an array that is outside the workflow that can be accessed from other workflows? Currently we are saving the values to a file but this is not the way we want to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need either an external database or a keyvalue store.

There a lots of database nodes for Node-RED that could do this or for a keyvalue pair you can use something like redis.

You can search on https://flows.nodered.org for [database](https://flows.nodered.org/?term=database&type=node&num_pages=1) and [redis](https://flows.nodered.org/?term=redis&type=node&num_pages=1) nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set global variables however they won't be retained when you restart node-red.  Here's an example for you.

```
[{"id":"5a6c6b8.2487294","type":"inject","z":"98c20df4.95abc","name":"","topic":"","payload":"val1","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":590,"y":260,"wires":[["e62b621d.37897"]]},{"id":"f83255b0.19aa48","type":"inject","z":"98c20df4.95abc","name":"","topic":"","payload":"val2","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":590,"y":300,"wires":[["e62b621d.37897"]]},{"id":"e62b621d.37897","type":"change","z":"98c20df4.95abc","name":"","rules":[{"t":"set","p":"testvar","pt":"global","to":"payload","tot":"msg"}],"action":"","property":"","from":"","to":"","reg":false,"x":810,"y":280,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"c99e3c90.ae63d","type":"inject","z":"98c20df4.95abc","name":"","topic":"","payload":"val1","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":590,"y":400,"wires":[["a72eed82.28ddd"]]},{"id":"940128d3.c5d0a8","type":"inject","z":"98c20df4.95abc","name":"","topic":"","payload":"val2","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":590,"y":440,"wires":[["a72eed82.28ddd"]]},{"id":"a72eed82.28ddd","type":"function","z":"98c20df4.95abc","name":"","func":"var compare = global.get(\"testvar\");\n\nif(typeof(compare)=='undefined'){\n    //Good idea to check if it's been set so you don't get 'undefined' errors\n    node.status({text:\"Global var has not been set yet\"});\n}else if(msg.payload == compare){\n    node.status({text:\"Same\"});\n}else{\n    node.status({text:\"NOT the same\"});\n}\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":767.01953125,"y":415.00390625,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"997cc65f.c8d238","type":"comment","z":"98c20df4.95abc","name":"Set the Global var here","info":"","x":560,"y":220,"wires":[]},{"id":"34e55934.227c16","type":"comment","z":"98c20df4.95abc","name":"Test the Global var here","info":"","x":560,"y":360,"wires":[]},{"id":"81bed25f.6022a","type":"inject","z":"98c20df4.95abc","name":"","topic":"","payload":"val1","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":590,"y":560,"wires":[["164c525e.b4f6ce"]]},{"id":"d03c41c8.088a","type":"inject","z":"98c20df4.95abc","name":"","topic":"","payload":"val2","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":590,"y":600,"wires":[["164c525e.b4f6ce"]]},{"id":"a4cd5575.a4cef8","type":"comment","z":"98c20df4.95abc","name":"Another way to set the Global var","info":"","x":590,"y":520,"wires":[]},{"id":"164c525e.b4f6ce","type":"function","z":"98c20df4.95abc","name":"","func":"global.set(\"testvar\",msg.payload);\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":770,"y":580,"wires":[[]]}]
```

Comment: Node Red now persists context from version 0.19, so this should be a viable solution (I haven't used it though). Refer to https://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#storing-data

Answer (score 0):

Try node-red-contrib-state it persists state across node-red restarts, and has a few other tools for state management.

mqtt is also good for saving state if you have access to an mqtt broker.